# Can Jackson remove the @JsonFilter restriction

Tags: java, json, jackson

My code use a default ObjectMapper without filters defined, but the target class with a @JsonFilter annotation. My expectation is to Jackson will ignore the annotation and do a normal thing.

And in another case, if I want to use the filter and I also give the filter defined, why must add @JsonFilter to the class otherwise jackson will work as no filter.

@JsonFilter looks a redundant thing. We already defined the filters. The real issue is the problem described at beginning. We can't modify the class with annotation, we just serialize the class with normal behavior.

There's way to create a dummy filter and set setFailOnUnknownId(false). But this looks not so general.

Comment: This sounds like a rant rather than a question. What are you hoping to find out from Stack Overflow users?

Comment: or a better solution if expertise can suggest.